# ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: sql, oracle

```
ALTER TABLE IDN_APPMGT_CLAIM_MAPPING 
ADD CONSTRAINT CLAIMID_APPID_CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (APP_ID) REFERENCES IDN_APPMGT_APP (ID) 
ON UPDATE RESTRICT
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

I want to translate this SQL to Oracle. Since Oracle does not have ON UPDATE RESTRICT I cannot imaging how this should be done. Will just omitting the ON UPDATE clause solve the problem?

```
ALTER TABLE IDN_APPMGT_CLAIM_MAPPING 
ADD CONSTRAINT CLAIMID_APPID_CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (APP_ID) REFERENCES IDN_APPMGT_APP (ID) 
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html,  `RESTRICT` in an `ON UPDATE` or `ON DELETE` clause:

> Rejects the delete or update operation for the parent table.

In other words, attempting to change a value in the parent table when rows in a child table reference this value will fail.

You can't specify an `ON UPDATE` clause in an Oracle foreign-key constraint, as Oracle doesn't support `ON UPDATE ...` options in foreign-key constraints.  However, that's not a problem for you as Oracle's behaviour with `UPDATE` statements and foreign-key constraints is the same as MySQL's behaviour with `ON UPDATE RESTRICT`.  In fact, `ON UPDATE RESTRICT` is the default in MySQL as well, so you could have just omitted it in both databases.

So, in summary, yes, omitting the `ON UPDATE RESTRICT` clause from the constraint will solve your problem.