# Creating SQL table

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I am trying to create the below table but Oracle telling me keyword missing. I have looked at the code I cant see a problem. Please help

```
CREATE TABLE lecture
(LectureID integer not null,
StartDate date not null,  
StartTime time not null,
EndTime time not null, 
TicketID integer not null, 
PRIMARY KEY (LectureID),
FOREIGN KEY (TicketID) REFERENCES ticket(TicketID) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

This is the error code i am getting

ORA-00905: missing keyword

Comment: Oracle does not have a `time` data type: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020

Comment: @Joseph . . . I believe both answers are correct.  You need to fix both the reference and the data type.

Comment: I need to achieve the ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE effect, how do I do that in oracle?

Comment: I updated the code but am still getting error "ORA-00911: invalid character"                    

CREATE TABLE lecture
(LectureID integer not null,
StartDate date,  
StartTime timestamp not null,
EndTime timestamp not null, 
TicketID integer not null, 
PRIMARY KEY (LectureID));
FOREIGN KEY (TicketID) REFERENCES ticket(TicketID));

Comment: PRIMARY KEY (LectureID)); = > PRIMARY KEY (LectureID)

Answer (score 0):

There is no "on update cascade" in Oracle

Answer (score 0):

time datatype is noe suppoerted in Oracle You will have following options for date time in oracle

```
 DATE, TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, and TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE.
```

For Datetime details you can refer :
[Click Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG004)

```
CREATE TABLE lecture
(LectureID integer not null,
StartDate date not null,  
StartTime TIMESTAMPnot null,
EndTime TIMESTAMPnot null, 
TicketID integer not null, 
PRIMARY KEY (LectureID),
FOREIGN KEY (TicketID) REFERENCES ticket(TicketID) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

Comment: @Joseph I am sorry forgot that Update cascade is not allow in the Oracle. It was my pleasure to help you

Comment: @Joseph this is the best artical for you to achieve your functionlaity : please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22871300/on-update-restrict-on-delete-cascade

Comment: I updated the code but am still getting error "ORA-00911: invalid character"                    

CREATE TABLE lecture
(LectureID integer not null,
StartDate date,  
StartTime timestamp not null,
EndTime timestamp not null, 
TicketID integer not null, 
PRIMARY KEY (LectureID));
FOREIGN KEY (TicketID) REFERENCES ticket(TicketID));

Comment: Thanks Hardik, exactly the explanation I needed

Comment: Was that link useful. Here is one more link that you will find very useful  http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_keys.php

Answer (score 0):

there is no ON UPDATE and DELETE RESTRICT clause in Oracle. These are mysql options

Comment: what clause can I use to acheive the same effect in oracle? thanks

Comment: You have only three DELETE options CASCADE, SET NULL or NO ACTION. You have to use NO ACTION clause. Oracle does not support CASCADE UPDATE. You have to write a trigger.

Comment: No clause will do in Oracle.Go with triggers.

Comment: CREATE TABLE lecture (
LectureID integer not null, 
StartDate date, 
StartTime timestamp not null,
EndTime timestamp not null, 
TicketID integer not null, 
PRIMARY KEY (LectureID), 
FOREIGN KEY (TicketID) 
REFERENCES ticket(TicketID)); You have to delete the extra semicolon

Comment: Thanks Guys that was helpful, i will sort it out. I am still a newbie in database. thanks for your patience.